# Wrap EditorForModel fields in bootstrap

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, editorformodel

I have a View in which a form is populated with `Html.EditorForModel`. This generates a default HTML structure like:

```
<div>
    <label for="something1">Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="something1" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="something1">Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="something1" />
</div>
```

But I want to wrap these elements in a Twitter Bootstrap form field. So it should become something like:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="something1">Title</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" name="something1" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="something2">Title</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" name="something2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

But how can I do this when the elements are generated through `Html.EditorForModel`?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create your own extension method.

```
Html.BootStrapEditorForModel
```

Then use TagBuilder objects to build the required HTML structure

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to view the source code of `EditorForModel` anywhere to use as the basis for a Bootstrap version? I checked the ASP web stack but couldn't locate the actual meat of the method.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [TwitterBootstrapMVC](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/). It has a lot of helpers you might find useful.

---

Disclaimer:
BMVC is not free for Bootstrap 3.
I'm the author of BMVC